# Cookie is set only when checkbox is checked, but not when it's unchecked

Tags: php, login-script

My current login script I made with PHP Is working, But when i try to login and uncheck "Remember me" It logs in, But does not set the required cookies, However, If i check the Remember box, It logs in and sets the cookies.
So the issue is, What causes it to happend?
My PHP CODE:

```
<?php
    /* Mysql data */
    $MysqlUsername = "root";
    $MysqlPassword = "";
    $MysqlHostname = "localhost";
    $MysqlDatabase = "teamgamersnet";
    $Salt = "TGN2012";
    $Username = $_POST['Username'];
    $Password = $_POST['Password'];
    $Remember = $_POST['Remember'];
    $Cookie = "TGN";
    $IP       = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
    if (empty($Username) || empty($Password)) { die("Please fill in all the fields"); }


    $hash = hash('sha256',strtolower($Username).$Password.$Salt);

    $Sql = new mysqli($MysqlHostname, $MysqlUsername, $MysqlPassword, $MysqlDatabase);
    if ($Sql->connect_error){ echo $Sql->connect_error; }
    $sUser = $Sql->real_escape_string($Username);
    $sPass = $Sql->real_escape_string($Password);
    $xPass = $Sql->real_escape_string($hash);


    $CheckUser = $Sql->query("SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `Username` = '".$sUser."'");;
    if ($CheckUser->num_rows == 0) { header("Location: /?p=Login&wrongusr=true"); die(); }
    $xCheckUser = $CheckUser->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
    if ($xCheckUser['Activated'] == "false") { header("Location: /?p=Login&activate=true"); die(); }
    if(strtolower($Username) == strtolower($xCheckUser['Username'])) {
        if($hash == $xCheckUser['Password']) { // Check if password is correct
        if(isset($Remember)){ // Set a looong cooke to remember
                setcookie ($Cookie."User", htmlspecialchars($Username), time() + 99999999);
                setcookie ($Cookie."Pass", $hash, time() + 99999999);
                        header("Location: /?login=true");

        }
        else
        { // Set a standard cookie
                setcookie ($Cookie."User", htmlspecialchars($Username), time() + 3600);
                setcookie ($Cookie."Pass", $hash, time() + 3600);
                header("Location: /?login=true");
        }

    }

    else
    {
        header("Location: /?p=Login&wrongpwd=true"); // Send them to home page 
    }
    }
?>
```

Comment: Why have you elected to invent your own login security?

Comment: With a checkbox no key value is passed to your php if its not checked, this is why `$Remember` wont be set if checkbox is not set. You should check that your $_POST values are set before setting to your local vars, at the same time you can set your `$Remember`

Comment: $Password is *always* set with your code.  This line: `$Password = $_POST['Password'];` sets the variable (even if the $_POST is not set).  Consider changing your logic to check if `$Remember` is a **value**.  And you can change how you set it: `$Remember = (isset($_POST['Remember'])) ? 1 : 0;` (because when a checkbox is not checked, the $_POST is not set for that input).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer to your question is not due to PHP itself, but (I think) down to your webserver. A bit of information about cookies and how they are set:
- They are based on a timestamp - more importantly, a timestamp set by the server!
- They will automatically expire based on the said timestamp.

I'd strongly suggest looking closely at the HTTP headers that are being sent by the server and checking the expiration date, as I was not able to reproduce your bug locally, but have had similar in production before.
Go on your page, uncheck remember me, and check headers sent to you by the server. You'll find something like this:
Set-Cookie:TGNPass=*some hash*; expires=Sat, 17-Nov-2012 22:27:44 GMT

The expiration date/time is what you are after. Check that it is what you are expecting (i.e. one hour from now), and if not, you'll need to adjust your server's timezone settings. This is easily done using http://php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-set.php .

Comment: I currenty disabled redirect, and checked what is in the headers, For the set-cookie, it gives the same time as i sendt the post. Set-Cookie:TGNUser=Teknikk; expires=Sat, 17-Nov-2012 22:35:55 GMT
Set-Cookie:TGNPass=CantShow; expires=Sat, 17-Nov-2012 22:35:55 GMT

Comment: Then your server's timezone is off by one hour. You'll need to set it correctly - use the function I linked to above to do so.

Comment: (at a complete tangent, if I were you, I'd avoid salting every password with the same value. This is completely equivalent to not salting at all, as the point of salting is to prevent a rainbow table attack on the hash. Consider using a different hash for every user)

Comment: Ok, Changed the time zone in php.ini, As the server time was correctly and the php.ini has it to somewhere in Asia when it's supposed to be in "Europe/Oslo". Accepted.

Answer (score 0):

From http://php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php sometimes time()+3600 fails if your server time does not match the client time.  I would try  time() + 7200 and time() + 14400 and inspect your cookies to see what they are actually set to.